# Why are my files comming through as binary?

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I have a html form that i want to allow file uploads. I can get it to send over the correct information but instead of receiving the file in its format i.e. jpg or pdf, i simply get an email full of binary.
Can anyone shed some light onto why this is happening ?

My html

```
 <form name="htmlform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../html_form_send.php">
            <table width="450px">
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td valign="top">
             <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
            </td>
             <td valign="top">
             <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td valign="top">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
            <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td valign="top">
            <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
            <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
            </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
             <td valign="top">
             <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
            <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
             <td valign="top">
             <label for="service">Service Required</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
            <input  type="text" name="service" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
             <td valign="top">
             <label for="file">If you have any drawings or images to submit please do so</label>
             </td>
            <td valign="top">
            <input type="file" name="attachment" ></textarea>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
             <td valign="top">
             <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
             </td>
            <td valign="top">
            <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
            </td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">   
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
```

My Php

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "matthew.p@cawthornes.co.uk";

    $email_subject = "website html form submissions";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['service']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])){
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }


    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $service = $_POST['service']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
    /* GET File Variables */
    $tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 


    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    if (file($tmpName)) {
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb');
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName));
  fclose($file);

  /* a boundary string */
  $randomVal = md5(time());
  $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x";

  /* Header for File Attachment */
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\"";

  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
  $message . "\n\n";

  /* Encoding file data */
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
 }





    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Service: ".clean_string($service)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
    $email_message .= "attachment:  ".clean_string($file)."\n";

     /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
    $email_message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
    " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n" .
     "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  



function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

<h3>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Content-Disposition: attachment` to the headers of the attachment part of your email.

Comment: thanks for the reply, iv added it to the headers part but still do not get any attachements